# Button click changes background image on body and also page refreshes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an assignment. There is a image button. When I click on the Image button, the background image present in the body has to change. By writing the code in C# i am able to change the background image with the image button click. But the page is refreshing for every background change. As per my assignment the page should not refresh for every background image change.(for reference see the bing page and click on the arrow to change the background image where the page will not refresh)

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        String filenames = "SELECT * FROM [Table]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(filenames, con);

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Table] ";

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        list1 = new ArrayList();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list1.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        HiddenField1.Value = ArrayListToString( ref list1);

         string ArrayListToString(ref ArrayList _ArrayList)
        {
            int intCount;
            string strFinal = "";

            for (intCount = 0; intCount <= _ArrayList.Count - 1; intCount++)
            {
                if (intCount > 0)
                {
                    strFinal += "~";
                }

                strFinal += _ArrayList[intCount].ToString();
            }

            return strFinal;
        }
```

Comment: Then you need to do the change in javascript.

Comment: the images will be loaded to the C# code via the Database where the images will be dynamically changed. How to transfer the Array List from C# to JQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

C# is server side language. So, when your click is going from your browser to a server. Server then returns an html for your browser page to render. Thus, refreshing the page.
You would need to change your code from C# to Javascript. 
If you are trying to get something from database, you will need do an AJAX call using Javascript.

I am assuming you are using ASP.Net. This is one way to do:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: I have the arrayList in the pageload of (aspx.cs)C#. How to make the Ajax Call using the JQuery to load it from C# to JavaScript ? or DO I need to retrieve the database values to directly  using JavaScript?